# Get records from Formidable Table using $wpdb->get_col

Tags: wpdb

I am using Formidable Pro as a CRM and one form has a field called cust_id.

Now I want to get all the records stored within that form with a specific cust_id.

I did:

$form_id = 7;
$search_id = 300;

$entries = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM ". $wpdb->prefix ."frm_items WHERE cust_id = %d AND form_id = %d", $search_id, $form_id) );

But the $entries are empty ??

And there are a few records with the search_id.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'frm_items';

$row_values = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE id = 1");

echo $row_values[0]->cust_id;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But maybe my question was not clear enough. What I have is: a form which is form_id 7. Within that form there is a field called cust_id. No I want to retreive all the record ID's when i.e. cust_id = 300 from form_id=7. I will give your suggestion a try anyway...

Comment: I have updated my answer just now. Maybe you'll need change id for form_id ?

Comment: Thanks again, but that doesn't do the trick also.

Comment: Can you please replace: echo $row_values[0]->cust_id; by >>> echo '<pre>'; print_r($row_values); and return me the array here: https://www.codepile.net/ . By the same time, can you please give me what you write in the $wpdb->get_results ?